Elements not being found through selenium even though they are undoubtedly there
I'm starting to build an arbitrage finder, and have started by trying to scrape all of the names of the sports from the following link:(https://www.allbritishcasino.com/en/sports-book/sports#/sport/66/category/885/championship/4625/eventType/m). The code for the first instance of one of the sports I'm trying to scrape is here:
<span class="SportMenustyled__SportMenuItemName-sc-66zbej-9 SportMenustyled__SportMenuSportName-sc-66zbej-10 dCqxBg hXeCJr">Football</span>

To scrape just the name from this, I've tried:
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'SportMenustyled__SportMenuItemName-sc-66zbej-9.SportMenustyled__SportMenuSportName-sc-66zbej-10.dCqxBg.hXeCJr')

driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'SportMenustyled__SportMenuItemName-sc-66zbej-9.SportMenustyled__SportMenuSportName-sc-66zbej-10.dCqxBg.hXeCJr')

and even
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/main/div[3]/div/div//div[1]/div[3]/aside/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/span[1]')

Funnily enough, the xpath in that line of code, which I got from finding the right place in html and copying relative xpath, is different to the one I got using selectorshub, which is:
/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/main[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]
Next, i looked into frames/iframes, but after inspection there's no evidence that these are present.
Finally, I tried:
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Football']")

Which once again returns nothing, which leads me to the conclusion that I'm being blocked from scraping the data somehow. All of the data from the website is available and is there in the selenium window when I use developer tools, just when I try it scrape it selenium returns the 'element cannot be located' error.
Also, for context, when inspecting the element in the chrome browser window selenium uses, everything is all there- the html is the same and the site looks the same.
So how would I scrape these elements? Am i being blocked from scraping it by the website? This would make sense as gambling sites obviously hate it when you do this. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks for any help.

the only way of blocking scraping is to block totally the page, which you said didn't happen. i don't use selenium but your css selector looks wrong, missing the first dot.

The xpath is also incorrect. It should be "//span[text()='Football']" or "//*[text()='Football']", but not "//div[text()='Football']"
